# How to navigate between inline views in react native

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I am working on a Wizard style sign up for and I don't want to create separate Components for each Wizard step. Instead, I want to use simple Views as steps and switch between them (with a transition).

I know this is not the best practice (to say the least) but I want to build something quick and dirty.

I am looking to use the navigator instead of a simple conditional rendering because I want to use the transitions which are built into the react native navigators.

This is an example of what I a looking to achieve:

```
personalDetails = () => {
    return (
      <View style={styles.content}>

      </View>
    );
  }


linkAccount = () => {
    return (
      <View style={styles.content}>

      </View>
    );
  }


<Navigator>
          <Card
            exact path="app/signup/personaldetails"
            component={this.personalDetails()}
          />
          <Card
            exact path="app/signup/linkaccount"
            component={this.linkAccount()}
          />
        </Navigator>
```

Comment: I'm sorry, I can't understand your question.

Comment: @BrightLee edited. Is it clearer? I am working on a Wizard style sign up for and I don't want to create separate Components for each Wizard step. Instead, I want to use simple Views and switch between them (with a transition).

Comment: Thanks for updating. Yeah, I understand. But I don't know if it's possible as far as I know. By the way, is there such as a `Navigator` in react-navigation?

Comment: @BrightLee There is. I don't mind using any other type of Navigator though

Comment: Why not use conditional rendering along with layout animation to allow transitioning as well? You can animate the way the next step shows up ( for example a fade in fade out effect)